# iOS Scrubbable Buttons

Tags: ios, gestures

On the keyboard and in the native calculator app on iOS, it's possible to put your finger down on one button, like '0', and then move your finger to the another button, like '1', release your finger, and have it enter '1'. On the calculator it darkens the button under your finger.

If you start pressing a button, drag your finger outside of the buttons, and then move it back in, it'll continue to highlight the buttons under your finger. However, if you don't start on a button—like you start dragging from the calculator results label—and drag onto the buttons, the buttons do not highlight.

What's the best approach to mimic the calculator's behaviour for buttons? I'm mostly looking for code structuring guidance rather than code examples here!

It seems I won't be encapsulate each button in its own view class, but I'll have to have a `Keyboard` that handles all the touches, and manually draws the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to add handling for touch control events:

```
UIControlEventTouchDragInside
UIControlEventTouchDragOutside
UIControlEventTouchDragEnter
```

And link all the components with some kind of processing logic. Initial control event location and so on.